# For loop code to one line code in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

Can someone explain the following loop code converted into a one line code?

Code:

```
total_price = 0
for cost in gift_costs:
    if cost < 25:
        total_price += cost * 1.08
```

Converted one line code:

```
total_price = (gift_costs[gift_costs < 25]).sum() * 1.08
```

Comment: "please explain this code" questions are typically off-topic here, unless you specify a very specific aspect you don't understand and there aren't any questions about that aspect already answered elsewhere on the site.

Comment: Moreover, it's important for code to be a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code someone can copy-and-paste without changes to see the behavior you're asking about. If we just set `gift_costs=[10 20 30 40]` your code [doesn't work](https://ideone.com/wMtpEF). I need to assume that your real `gifts_cost` is an object created using a library that isn't specified in the question.

Comment: Read about list comprehension in Python

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, ...except this code _isn't_ a list comprehension. (I first closed the question as a duplicate of one on the subject, since that's the obvious assumption given the title and context -- but take a closer look; it's not, hence being reopened).

Comment: are these numpy arrays?

Comment: I would suggest breaking the code into smaller portions, running them and seeing the output. The code seems self explainable.

Comment: @Charles Duffy The initialization should be `gift_costs=[10, 20, 30, 40]`. You missed the commas and there is a syntax error.

Comment: @Charles fair enough, my mistake. If those are numpy arrays it would make sense, but yes, the question should have the full code

Comment: @xuhdev, still fails later even with that correct, though, unless one uses numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are not explicitly saying it, but it's pretty much clear that you're using numpy arrays. So let's break that line down, taking some arbitrary array as an example:

```
>>> gift_costs = numpy.array([10, 22, 35, 41])
>>> total_price = (gift_costs[gift_costs < 25]).sum() * 1.08
>>> total_price
34.56
```

1. `total_price =`  : What is on the right side of the expression is going to be assigned to the `total_price` variable.
2. `gift_costs < 25` : Whenever you use a comparison operator (such as `<`) along with a numpy array, that conditional statement is going to be evaluated for each item of the array. Then, you're going to get a new array filled with boolean values, which are going to be `True` if a given value matches the condition, or `False` otherwise. So, for the above example, you would get the following: `array([True, True, False, False])`
3. `gift_costs[gift_costs < 25]` : Considering what we have just mentioned above, we are now asking `gift_costs` to return its values which position in the following sequence are `True`: `[True,  True, False, False]`. Those elements are: 10 and 22, and the returned object is: `array([10, 22])`
4. `.sum()` : Numpy array objects have a method called `sum()`, which returns the [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) (∑) of the array. In our example, this is 10 + 22 = 32.
5. `* 1.08` : Finally, the value returned by the `sum()` method (32) is multiplied by 1.08, which equals to 34.56

---

*Disclaimer:* Excuse me for my English, I tried to make myself clear the best I could.

Answer (score 0):

We can also code in a line without numpy.
Plz check this one.

```
l = [10, 22, 35, 41]

t = sum((x for x in l if x <25))*1.08
```

I used sum function and make a generator for the argument of the function.
The equation of generator is simple. Just read it as followings.
"take an x in list l if it is less than 25"
The generator gathering all the x in the condition and then transfer to the sum function...

Looks simple, doesn't it???

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same thing.
The for loop uses an if clause to identify cost <25 and subsequently applies to them the multiplication * 1.08.
The one clause filters using the [gift_costs < 25] and subsequently applies the same multiplication.
Another possibility (also more efficient in terms of computing time) is a list comprehension.